# Git bash não aceita o comando colar

Tags: git, bash

Gostaria de saber por que o git bash não aceita o comando ctrl+V. Toda vez que tenho que clonar um repositório no github tenho que digitar toda a url!

Comment: Se você clicar com o direito, aparece a opção "Colar". Talvez até com o atalho `Shift+Insert`.

Comment: Experimenta usar o botão do meio do rato para colar. Como o comando ctrl+c no terminal nada tem a ver com colar, acho que faz sentido o ctrl+v também não funcionar. Ficando  disponivel com a adição da tecla shift

Comment: Se estiver no linux ctrl+shift+v

Comment: Deu certo pessoal obrigado pela ajuda estou começando agora com o Git Bash, clicando o botão do meio do mouse ele cola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comandos como Ctrl+c e Ctrl+v no *bash* não correspondem a copiar e colar respectivamente.

Para ambiente *Windows*, as opções abaixo funcionam:

- Experimente clicando com o botão direito do mouse, assim:

[image: screenshot do gitbash]

- Ou também poderá usar o botão do meio do mouse (opção sugerida por lazyFox).

Obs.: Já trabalhei em outras versões do *bash*, onde clicando com o botão no ícone do canto superior, era exibida uma opção para colar também. Testei aqui a opção <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**Insert**</kbd> (citada na resposta do LINQ) funcionou também.

Comment: Um pessoa a perder tempo, a adicionar conteúdo a uma resposta e simplesmente desprezam a alteração -.-'

Comment: @lazyFox Obrigado pela dica do botão do meio.

Answer (score 5):

No Git Bash (e em vários outros softwares) <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**Insert**</kbd> cola o texto que estiver na área de transferência.

Comment: Meu teclado não possui a tecla Insert, algum outro caminho alternativo de atalho de teclado pra realizar a cópia e a colagem? (Além do que você tem que clicar com o mouse)

Answer (score 2):

Para alguns, como eu, que o teclado não tem a tecla `Insert`, tem um outro atalho de teclado para o Git Bash que permite copiar e colar.

Basta seguir os passos:

1. Clicar com o botão direito e clicar em "Options..."
2. Selecionar o menu Keys e desmarcar a opção "Copy and Paste" (como está ilustrado na figura abaixo)

   [image: Options do git bash]
3. Clicar em "Apply" e depois em "Save".

Depois de fazer essa configuração basta usar o comando `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`C` para copiar e `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V` para colar.

Answer (score 0):

No git (versão 2.21-64bit-ambiente windows 7) - eu simplesmete apertei o botão `Insert` e ele colou todo o caminho do diretorio que copiei.

Vlw. Espero que ajude.